# Powerline vs Mesh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a broadband plan with myrepublic which gives 1gbps, using the myrepublic halo router which is about 7m away from my desktop

Currently, I am using the Dlink DWA-192 AC1900 as my wifi adapter and the speed test from my room would gives 51mbps DOWN and 81mbps UP

I would like to upgrade my connectivity as I started hosting a media server on my computer and when too many people are streaming, the network gets laggy.

I am considering between two options,

1) One of those newer AV2000 powerlines - If I can get close to LAN speed, that would be really great. However most AV2000 do not have Singapore socket head and getting a electric outlet in my room is a little troublesome as my computer area only has 1.

2) Mesh networks - One of those newer triband mesh networks, the setup would be 1 mesh right at my desktop, wired by ethernet port to my PC. Hopefully, the signal is stronger and my family can benefit from the better connectivity too (I can get up to 8mbps DOWN 130mbps UP by using ookla speed test app on my phone when next to router)

Right now the speed of 81mbps UP is enough however I need it to be stable. Which would be a better investment? Powerline or mesh

Comment: And why is regular copper Ethernet not an option?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Singapore power outlet is a type G or UK power outlet. Nearly all powerline adapters come in UK style option. Let me explain one thing first the advertised speed for the powerline adapter and real life speed are far and few. Powerline transmission might provide a more stable connection with less ping time, but at the expense of a far lower bit-rate than the ISP is giving you.

Mesh net router setup would be the better option in your case. If outright download/upload speed is what your after then this is for you. The connection is more than stable enough and you can have extreme amount of devices connected to the system.

But if you only need just say another LAN/CAT outlet on the other side of the wall. Then putting in LAN input/output is another option. (wall to wall)|+|--|+|

Comment: Also add that PLC has another significant drawback: Since power lines are rarely (if at all) shielded, that is going to turn the power grid in the house into a gigantic antenna, and any signals on the wire are capable of traveling quite far (in excess of 300 m, depending on Tx power) - all of which is most likely going to cause a lot of interference in the neighborhood.